# Copy styled text out of UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, copy-paste

I have a UIWebView containing formatted HTML (with bold text, italic text, etc) in my application running on iOS 6.1.

When the user highlights the contents of the UIWebView and copies text out of it, then pastes it into (for example) Pages, it only pastes the plain text, not the styles. Is this the intended behavior for UIWebView? Is there a way to have it copy the text styles as well?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Got almost same issue. In iOS 9 Bold, Italic and Underline styles are copied, but font size & color are not.